# Fit a variable amount of webcams into a flexible div

Tags: html, css

We have a website with a live classroom with students on webcams. We display them all in a div:

```
<div id="webcams">
   <div class="webcam"><video...></div>
   <div class="webcam"><video...></div>
  [...]
</div>
```

The `#webcam` div takes up about 1/3rd of the view, but its size is set based on a) browser window size and b) is resizable with [react-split](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-split). So we don't really know how big it is, or even its rough dimensions (e.g. if it's tall or wide).

We also don't know how many students will be in a class - somewhere between 1 and 20, let's say.

I would like the webcams to fill up the `#webcam` div. For example:

- if there is a single student, the sole `.webcam` should take up the full width, and as much height as is suitable.
- if there are two students, the webcams should take 50% width each, OR be stacked on top of each other, depending on if the `#webcam` div is wider or taller
- if there are many students, they should be shrunk in size and tiled, but none should overflow below/out of the `#webcam` div - all should be visible at a time.

Can I do this with plain CSS?

Comment: Why are you using `className` and not `class`? For me, using it doesn't work.

Comment: oops - too much React lately. I'll change that

Comment: grid might help: here is an idea you can play with  : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BaVNowM there's 4 grids , the first one is rezibale (3 others will resize accordingly for the demo. put a random numbers of div in each grid to test behavior